# Knot invariants in 3-manifolds that are not $\mathbb{R}^3$ or $S^3$ or $B^3$?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory

This is just a reference request; I have no sharp mathematical question.

Inspired by the $(3+)$-year old MO question,
[In knot theory: Benefits of working in $S^3$ instead of $\mathbb{R}^3$?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/63158/6094),
I would like to ask:

> **Q1**. Are there are studies of
>   knot polynomial invariants in
>   [the $8$ Thurston geometries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrization_conjecture#The_eight_Thurston_geometries)?

Alternatively:

> **Q2**. Are there substantive differences between the various 3-manifolds
>   with respect to knot invariants?

(*Added*:) Gregory Moore says, "In general [in other 3-manifolds],
the knot polynomials no longer have integer
coefficients,..." (p.12 of "Physical Mathematics and the Future" (2014).
[PDF download of 56-page paper](http://www.physics.rutgers.edu/~gmoore/PhysicalMathematicsAndFuture.pdf).)

Comment: Q1: I guess Witten's [Z-invariant](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01217730) can be viewed as such: it captures simultaneously the topology of a "Wilson loop" (a.k.a. knot) and the ambient manifold. Kauffman's "Knots and Physics" has some relevant chapter. As I recall from my student years there was some activity on the subject in 1990s.

Comment: Q2: A non-simply-connected manifold would have more than one "unknot", which implies there is a difference. Perhaps I misunderstood what kind of difference you are looking at.

Comment: Another interesting question relating topology of 3- and 4- manifolds to knot invariants stems from Kirby calculus. In fact, one of the 1st papers on Jones-like polynomials was computing a discrete invariant of knots under Kirby moves, which implies an invariant of the manifold obtained via surgery on those knots.

Comment: Witten's *Quantum field theory and the Jones polynomial*: "the Jones polynomial can be generalized from $S^3$ to arbitrary three manifolds..." Thanks, @Michael, very apropos.

Comment: @Michael: I just meant Q2 to be a more specific query than Q1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For question 1) Yes analogs of knot invariants exist for any manifold regardless of prime decomposition or Thurston decomposition. For example, consider the Alexander polynomial and its categorification, knot Floer homology. These can both defined for general one cusped 3-manifolds. Computations of these invariants have been used lately to answer the question: Given a homology class $\mathcal{s}$ in a manifold $M$, is there a knot $K$ such that as a curve in $M$, $K \in \mathcal{s}$ and $S^3-K' \cong M-K$ for some knot $K'$ in $S^3$. This question is equivalent to if $M$ can be realized as surgery along a knot in $S^3$.

For example, Josh Greene was able to show here that if a knot in $S^3$ admits a lens space surgery then its knot Floer homology appears on a confined (but infinite) list of known examples, [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1010.6257.pdf). Margaret Doig offers a nearly complete classification knots in elliptic manifolds that admit an $S^3$ surgery in these [two](http://arxiv.org/abs/1201.4187) [papers](http://arxiv.org/abs/1302.6130). And recently, Yi Ni and Xingru Zhang places significant restrictions on knots in certain Nil manifolds that could admit $S^3$ surgeries [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.0648v1.pdf). These are all examples of exploiting knot invariants in closed manifolds.

For question 2) I think the consensus is that knot invariants are more delicate in non-simply connected manifolds. As brought up in the comments, there could be several different analogs of the unknot. One analog of unknottedness is minimal with respect to Seifert genus, i.e. a knot is minimal if for all simple closed curves in its homology class of a manifold there is no curve that bounds a lower genus (orientable) surface. However, even this question is considerably harder. There is some hope that there might be a polynomial time algorithm for recognition of the unknot in $S^3$. Along these lines, Agol, Haas, and Thurston show that just determining the genus of a knot in general 3-manifold is NP-Hard, [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0205057.pdf).

Comment: Thank you! Especially the comments on the "several different analogs of the unknot" are illuminating.